# How to call java class from ILOG JRules business rules

Tags: java, business-rules, ilog

How to call java class from ILOG JRules ? Is there any way or alternative ? kindly share.

Well we have in a situation like we have to call a java class method in ruleset. As particular case does match in business rule then we need to call the particular method of a java class.

The similar thing we can done Using Oracle Rule Author by using **Call JavaClass.JavaMethod()**

We don't know how to perform the same task in ILOG JRules

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the way we did in our project.

The classes you want to invoke from within your business rule can be imported in the rule studio and create BOM (business object model) out those classes. Make sure you verbalize the methods you want to invoke from those classes. Once you have verbalization available for the methods you want to invoke, very easily those can be invoked from your business rule.